# How to resolve "Could not get unknown property 'shadow' for project of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Tags: spring, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, shadowjar

plugin used : id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '4.0.4'

Gradle : https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip

getting error :

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'iot-bulk-slice-worker'.
> Could not get unknown property 'shadow' for project of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

for :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '4.0.4'
    //id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.1'


}



if (subproject.name in gradle.platforms) {
        subproject.publishing {
            publications {
                code(MavenPublication) { publication ->
                    publication.artifactId = gradle.platforms ['artifactName']
                    from components.java
                }
                shadow(MavenPublication) { publication ->
                    publication.artifactId ="${subproject.name}"
                    subproject.shadow.component(publication)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of the build file? (For instance, how the plugin is applied and how the publication fits in with the publishing block.)

Comment: Version 4.x is pretty old. Depending on your java version try 5, 6, or 7.

Comment: @BjørnVester updated the snippet, please check.

Comment: @M.Deinum , tried with 7.1.1, it gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still a little difficult to say without the complete build file. But I assume the `subproject` variable is exactly that - a subproject. In that case, you are configuring a publication on a subproject that uses the `shadow` extension from itself.

This means to `shadow` plugin has to be applied to the subproject. From the snippets, you are only applying it to the root project.

Could be something like this:

```java
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '4.0.4' apply false // <-- Set to false if the root project does not itself need to be "shadowed". This still makes the plugin available on the build classpath for subprojects.
}

subprojects { subproject ->
    if (...) {
        subproject.apply(plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow')
        // publications here...
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped to resolve the issue , Thank You !